# CreatePkgDef : error : BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I have created extension for Visual Studio, which is working fine for Windows7. 
My extension is working perfect on windows 7. But on windows 10 its not working. (Problem is i am using IntPtr and on windows 10 its not able to store 64bit address giving exception of arithmetic operation failed). Now trying to build it for 64 bit systems(so that intptr should be of size 8) I am getting error CreatePkgDef : error : BadImageFormatException. 
I have tried with setting all possible configuration settings to point it to build to 64 bit but had no luck. Even i tried all dependent dll's are loadable in 64 bit build so not able to figure out which setting is missing.

Comment: May i have put it in wrong words. My extension is working perfect on windows 7. But on windows 10 its not working. (Problem is i am using IntPtr and on windows 10 its not able to store 64bit address giving exception of arithmetic operation failed). Sorry for not being correct while puting quetion @John

Comment: CreatePkgDef expects x86 code, not x64, you can't go around that. You want to get back to the original reason why your extension is failing *exactly* in the first place (what's the error, stacktrace, etc.)?

Comment: Show us the code that is failing

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. As of the time of this question and answer, there is no 64-bit Visual Studio. All Visual Studio extensions must be 32-bit.

Comment: May i have put it in wrong words. My extension is working perfect on windows 7. But on windows 10 its not working. (Problem is i am using IntPtr and on windows 10 its not able to store 64bit address giving exception of arithmetic operation failed). Sorry for not being correct while puting quetion http://stackoverflow.com/users/5359922/john